# before and after attributes are not working in local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having a 'standard compare product' feature on product page, which is basically comparision of current product with the standard one. I called that block in local.xml like

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content"> 
         <block type="compare/product" name="myblock" before="product.info.upsell" template="compare/product.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The problem is when I use before attribute it is putting the template in the beginning of content, When I use after it is placing at the end. I want to put it after description or below the upsell products, How we can do that? Why before and after attributes are not working here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want display it between description or upsell product ?

Comment: @SHPatel I want to display it either after description tabs or before upsell products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround for it.in local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info"> 
         <block type="compare/product" name="myblock" template="compare/product.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then called myblock in view.phtml
before

```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

but, It would be better if it is done in local.xml using before or after attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
/home/builderroof/public_html/app/design/frontend/your-theme/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

add your blcok after

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
```

Comment: Thanks for workaround, can't we do this in local.xml?

Comment: yes you have to change reference name

Comment: change reference name to what?

Comment: <reference name="product.info">

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml">
                    <block type="custom/myblock" name="myblock"  template="custom/myblock.phtml"/>
         </block>
    </reference>    
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: oh yes, I tried the same thing, anyway thanks :)

Comment: if this solved your problem mark as accepted

Comment: still couldn't understand why before and after attributes are not working in local.xml

Comment: I believe before and after work only in core/text_list and similar(descendant) blocks, i.e. blocks which just render blocks their nested blocks.

Comment: yes and content is indeed a core/text_list block